# Reusable components with different NgRx actions

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-component-store

I'm currently developing an Angular app that uses NgRx as its state management solution. The app consists of different pages which each correspond to separate feature state.

I've also developed a set of reusable components that can be used in each feature. The components can emit a set of actions that influence the feature state.

I'm running into a problem now on how to "configure" which actions these shared components will dispatch.

For example: in feature A, the save button of my component should emit SAVE_A, while in feature B this should be SAVE_B.

I think I could solve it by using `@Output` then wiring the emits in the corresponding parent components, but this feels dirty and, seeing as these components are used throughout the app, I would like to avoid having to set up this wiring each time.

Alternatively, I could develop a set of wrapping components (`SaveAButton`, `SaveBButton`) and set up the link between the store and the reusable component there, but again this feels like I'm missing a point and that there should be an easier solution to this problem.

What would be a proper and clean solution to have reusable components directly tied to the store?

Comment: I don't know exactly how your code logic is implemented but, given your reusable `save button` component, using an `Output` is the correct way, not a dirty one. Using `Input`s and `Output`s is a valid communication way between components, why is it dirty?

Why would a reusable component need to know what `action` needs to trigger? those types of components are generally `dumb` components, the smart/parent ones should decide what logic comes next.

Comment: Outputs are actually the clean way of doing this. For your components to be completely independent of their context, they should simply emit a "save" event which the consuming parent component links to the appropriate actions. What objections would you have to this approach? Why do you feel it to be "dirty"?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I mainly find it dirty because I would have to wire the outputs everywhere I use the components, and they're widely used in my app